# Why does hibernate 5.3 not support transactional caches with infinispan

Tags: hibernate, infinispan, second-level-cache

Dear Infinispan community

I run application in EAP and Spring deployment. After migrating dependencies from EAP 7.1 to EAP 7.2 I get warning in spring mode: `HHH025030: Transactional caches are not supported. The configuration option will be ignored; please unset` when using transaction tag in infinispan.xml - same applies in local-cache-configuration or invalidation-cache-configuration

```
<local-cache-configuration name="my-region">
    <transaction mode="NON_DURABLE_XA" transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup"/>
    <expiration ... />
    <memory>
        <object size="..." strategy="LRU" />
    </memory>
</local-cache-configuration>

<!-- OR -->

<invalidation-cache-configuration name="my-region">
    <locking concurrency-level="32" acquire-timeout="15000"/>
    <transaction mode="NON_DURABLE_XA" transaction-manager-lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup"/>
    <expiration ... />
    <memory>
        <object size="..." strategy="LRU" />
    </memory>
</invalidation-cache-configuration>
```

I found [ticket](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-10638)  saying that EAP should remove transaction tag but without explanation why.
The closest explanation I found is in the comment for pull request [infinispan!5900](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/pull/5900) which says `v53 drops support for transactional caches completely.` but documentation for Hibernate [5.3.20.Final](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/chapters/caching/Caching.html) or [5.4.28.Final](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) doesn't mention anything related and still lists transactional concurrency strategy.

What is the impact in hibernate 2LC that Infinispan configuration does not support transaction tag?

My usecase cares if 2LC cache for entity get invalidated **after** row was committed into DB (to behave like SQL query with transaction level read-committed). If transaction T1 updates entity in version V1 to V2 then transaction T2 should keep using entity V1 until transaction T1 commits in DB. If transaction T1 rollbacks then triggering cache invalidation is still fine for me as I don't use replicated cache, but invalidation-cache.

I use entity with annotation `org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(region = "my-region", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)`.

Which concurrency strategy should I use in that case and how to configure Infinispan cache?

Does CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL strategy use XA Resource to clean the cache **after** row was committed into DB.

Is there documentation or tests how Infinispan behaves in such edge cases with hibernate 2LC?

Versions: EAP 7.2 / Spring 5.x - hibernate-core:5.3.15.Final-redhat-00001, infinispan-hibernate-cache-v53:9.3.8.Final-redhat-00001

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Hibernate 2LC integration. [Infinispan documentation](https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/integrating/integrating.html#cache_strategies) says (you have the full context in the link):

```
Infinispan provides the same consistency guarantees for both transactional and read-write strategies, use of transactions is considered an implementation detail.
```

Does it help you?

Comment: Thanks @pruivo I went through various documentations but missed that section. I believe cache invalidation happens on some hibernate listener triggered after DB commit and I would be nice to find documentation - it shows example for stale read nonstrict-read-write but it would be good to understand how read-write protects against that (which is supposed to be more strict). I will leave that question opened for some time to see if someone has something to add.

Comment: That link says 'Hibernate supports JDBC-only transactions' - but hibernate can use XA DB connection working together with XA JMS connection but usually 2LC is not mentioned to be configured in XA mode in such setup.

Comment: @kodstark that note applies to Hibernate < 5.3 only, and says that you should not use transactional Infinispan caches when Hibernate is using JDBC-only transactions.

Comment: @DanBerindei Does it mean that I should expect that line "HHH025030: Transactional caches are not supported" to not being in logs if Hibernate 5.3 is configured for XA datasource working together with JMS?

Comment: @kodstark I was talking only about that note that says "Use of transactional caches is possible only in JTA environment. Hibernate supports JDBC-only transactions but Infinispan transactional caches do not integrate with these." It means transactional caches require JTA in Hibernate < 5.3, but it doesn't change the fact that transactional caches do not work in Hibernate 5.3.